# extra blank space in HTML (decrease size)

Tags: html, css

My problem seems simple but yet I have tried everything and I cant come up with the answer. I am developing a website and on my main template I have an extra blank space either on both sides or on one side of the page because my HTML is wider than my main container, I would like to decrease the width of it so that the container fits the screen. any suggestions? I have seen the answers posted here before and it didnt help.

Comment: post your html code here

Comment: it seems like your problem is on `padding` or `margin`, but why use a template? If you are like really bad, use website builders.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really decrease the size of the html, the html is the size of the "viewport" which is the part where the webpage is displayed.

You can try this :

```
body {
  width:100%;
  margin:0%;
  padding:0%;
}
```

So your main (body) container is the same size as the html and there will be no white sides.

This is a long shot as there is no code here to work with to see what you are actually talking about.